# I added a Static IP using the same name

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, static, ip, virtual-machine

I added a Static IP usind the same name as a previous one. Now my VM's don't show anymore in the Extenal IP Page[External IP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBMw3.jpg)

Comment: I recommend reporting to Google as a bug: https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker

Comment: It's not the proper channel to report about Google Cloud related issues. If you think that you found an issue you should follow documentation [Report Issues and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Please update your question with your troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thank you. I did. Google is looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks like related to Google Cloud services and should be reported to Google.

**To solve this issue** you should follow documentation [Report Issues and Request Features with Issue Trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports).